# read file content and get the values back

Tags: ios, swift

I have an function to write some numbers to a file

```
fun writeNumToFile -> Void {
    //get Documents’ path
  let docPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true).last as? String
  let filePath = docPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(“myFlie.txt”)

  //the count is NOT the count of elements in the array below.
  //think it as an independent constant.
  let count = 10
  //Write count to file
   String(count).writeToFile(filePath, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil);

  //Write an array of numbers to file
  for idx in [1,2,3] {
   String(idx as! String).writeToFile(filePath, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil);
  }
}
```

Now I want to read the numbers back from file, I know I can read the content of file by:

```
let fileContent = String(contentsOfFile: filePath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
```

but how can I get `count` & `[1,2,3]` array back once I get the content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing code as if you are using low-level file i/o. You're not. The `writeToFile:atomically:` methods that you are using overwrite a file with new contents, not append data to an existing file. your second write deletes the contents of your first write.

`NSArray` supports the `writeToFile:atomically:` method, and a `[String]` array should be inter-operable with NSArray.

You should be able to simply say:

```
let array = [1, 2, 3]
let ok = array .writeToFile(filePath, atomically: false)
```

Then later,

```
let array = NSArray.contentsOfFile(filePath)
```

I say "should be able to" because I am still learning the subtleties of interaction between Swift and the Foundation classes.

### EDIT:

If you need to save multiple discrete things into a file, create a dictionary:

```
let someValue = 42
let anArray = [1, 2, 3]
let aDictionary = [
  "someValue": someValue, 
  "array": anArray]
let ok = aDictionary.writeToFile(filePath, atomically: false)
```

and to read it:

```
let aDictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: filePath)
let someValue = aDictionary["someValue"] as! Int
let anArray = aDictionary["array"] as! [Int]
```

There is no need to save the number of items in the array separately. The array is able to reconstitute itself from the file contents, including the correct count of elements.

### EDIT #2:

Note that iOS includes the C file i/o library, which should be callable from Swift. If you are glutton for punishment you could do what you are trying to do using `fopen()`, `fseek()`, `fwrite()`, etc. (But don't. It's much more work, much more error-prone, and a non-standard way of doing it in iOS or Mac OS.)

Comment: Thanks, got your point. but I need to write the `count` and array into one file & read them out from file, that's the main point of my question, you only shows how to write and read just arrays.

Comment: You don't need to write the count. The array methods take care of that for you.

Comment: If you want to save a count value and an array, put all the contents into a dictionary and write that dictionary using `writeToFile:atomically:`

Comment: No, the `count` has nothing to do with array, it is not the number of elements in array, think it as a independent constant. My question is asking how to write two type of values to a file and read them back.

Comment: Thanks, but why `atomically` is set to `false`? And could you please show also how the dictionary could be read from file?

Comment: The atomically parameter can be set either way. `atomically = true` makes the file write more robust and error resistant, but takes longer and uses a little more disk space